# Unamed columns in excel imported file

Tags: python, python-import, import-from-excel

I imported a file ising `QA= pd.read_excel("/.../.../QA.xlsx",sheet_name='data',engine='openpyxl')` 
Yet I am getting an output in python with unnamed columns (Unnamed 0, Unnamed 1,...) and values where there should not be. I would note that the format of the file is very special including filters and column structure. For that you may find a screenshot of it:
[image]

Comment: I think you should pass arguments for the `header` and the `skiprows` parameters. It seems that the first row in the sheet is empty. [See](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Comment: @kaymal Thank you kaymal. I opted for a more standard solution. I restructured the excel sheet manually to have normal columns.  I will try your solution on another file and see whether it works or not
Best regards.